# HTML form- will not display along with a link in a straight line

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing a form and a link, that i wish to display in a straight line. The form displays correctly.... the link returns to the next line and is completely outside the div. I've combed through both the html and css and can not find an issue.

Note that I've already tried to do `white-space:nowrap`.

The div's HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
        <form action="" method="post">
        <b>Text Here</b>
        <input type="radio" name="" value="">Option</input>
        <input type="radio" name="" value="">Option</input>
        <input type="search" placeholder="">
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Search!">
        </form>
        <a href="">Compose</a>
    </div>
```

The div's CSS:

```
 .container{
    margin-top: 5px;
    float: right;
    width: 75%;
    height: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use class for both `form` & `link` with `display: inline-block;`

```css
.container{
    margin-top: 5px;
    float: right;
    width: 75%;
    height: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

form {
  display: inline-block;
}

.link {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <form action="" method="post">
        <b>Text Here</b>
        <input type="radio" name="" value="" />Option
        <input type="radio" name="" value="" />Option
        <input type="search" placeholder="" />
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Search!" />
     </form>
     <a href="" class="link">Compose</a>
</div>
```

Comment: welcome :) you can accept as answer if it solve your problem. Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Your `<a>` tag is outside of your `<form>`. Simply including it inside of the form will bring all elements in a line. Also, `<input>` is a void element, so does not have a closing tag.

This is fixed in the following:

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: right;
  width: 75%;
  height: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <b>Text Here</b>
    <input type="radio" name="" value="" />Option
    <input type="radio" name="" value="" />Option
    <input type="search" placeholder="" />
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Search!">
    <a href="">Compose</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

If you want the link to be outside of the `<form>`, you'll want to give both `display: inline-block` and the `<form>` a `width` small enough to contain the link on the same line. In the following, I've given both elements a `width` of `50%`:

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: right;
  width: 75%;
  height: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

form, a {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <b>Text Here</b>
    <input type="radio" name="" value="" />Option
    <input type="radio" name="" value="" />Option
    <input type="search" placeholder="" />
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Search!">
  </form>
  <a href="">Compose</a>
</div>
```

Note, however, that there isn't actually enough space to contain all of this information on one line at a narrow width, so you'll likely want to add a scroll or drop some information down to the next line inside of a media query.

Comment: `compose` link is inside text box in this case. it should come after `search` button